# Novel scientist's daughter breaks through to 4th dimension

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel as a teen about  a girl who was trained  by her scientist  father to break  4th dimension.  I remember isolation tanks  and chess games were involved.  The father really pushed  his daughter  through  the experiments.  There may have been a phrase like breaking through  the wall or elevator... I read this in the 1980's.  Yes, she did break through!

Answer (score 2):

*The Universe Between* by Alan Nourse? It's in two parts - in the second part her son has visited the other dimension many times, and can function in it. From the [Google Books description](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Universe_Between.html?id=rjEkAgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> Bob Benedict is one of the few scientists able to make contact with the invisible, dangerous world of The Thresholders and return - sane! For years he has tried to transport - and receive - matter by transmitting it through the mysterious, parallel Threshold. At first his efforts met only with failure and madness. But now The Thresholders have risen in fury. Somehow Bob Benedict must make one more trip into that land of peril and pacify them before they succeed in hurling his planet - piece by piece - into the oblivion of infinity.

Comment: Thanks but it was definitely a female character.  Her father basically  trained her and the  she broke through. It was as if her life was a series of experiments...that's how I remember it.

Comment: In the first part a teenage girl is used by scientists to break through, Then she learns how to 'twist' and escapes from the laboratory. The second part concerns her son.